# Выборка данных SQL

Tags: sql

Есть 2 простые таблицы.

```
1: id/name
2: id/time
```

Нужно вывести таблицу name/time, при этом выбрав последнее время из второй таблицы.

```
select t1.name as c1,
t2.time as c2
from t1
left join t2
on t1.id=t2.id
```

Собственно, как выбрать данные из второй таблицы, никак не соображу.

Comment: Указывайте СУБД, включая версию. Или используйте группирующий подзапрос по второй таблице - сработает везде.

Answer (score 0):

Если `time` - строковый тип данных, то можно сделать, например, так:

```sql
select 
    t1.name as c1, 
    (
        select 
            max(datetime(t2.time)) 
        from t2 where t2.id = t1.id
    ) as c2 
from t1
```

Comment: Коррелированный подзапрос. На некоторых СУБД - пофиг, на остальных - тормоза. Плюс полная непрозрачность происходящего.